# Bluetooth not working on XPS 13 9360 running 16.04.1

Tags: 16.04, bluetooth, dell, intel, xps

I have an XPS13 9360 running Ubuntu 16.04.1 equipped with an Intel 8265 Dual Band wireless card.

The card was not recognized at first, but after installing linux-generic-hwe-edge package WiFi started working flawlessly, but unfortunately I was not able to get bluetooth working.

If i navigate to system settings -> bluetooth, the bluetooth switch is set to off, but even if I set it to on, nothing changes.

```
$ lspci -nn
3a:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Intel Corporation Device [8086:24fd] (rev 78)

$ rfkill list all
    0: hci0: Bluetooth
        Soft blocked: no
        Hard blocked: no
    1: phy0: Wireless LAN
        Soft blocked: no
        Hard blocked: no

$ uname -r
4.8.0-34-generic
```

Can you help me please?

EDIT

```
$ dmesg | grep -i blue
[    8.311057] Bluetooth: Core ver 2.21
[    8.311070] Bluetooth: HCI device and connection manager initialized
[    8.311072] Bluetooth: HCI socket layer initialized
[    8.311074] Bluetooth: L2CAP socket layer initialized
[    8.311078] Bluetooth: SCO socket layer initialized
[    8.323674] Bluetooth: HCI UART driver ver 2.3
[    8.323675] Bluetooth: HCI UART protocol H4 registered
[    8.323676] Bluetooth: HCI UART protocol BCSP registered
[    8.323676] Bluetooth: HCI UART protocol LL registered
[    8.323676] Bluetooth: HCI UART protocol ATH3K registered
[    8.323677] Bluetooth: HCI UART protocol Three-wire (H5) registered
[    8.323702] Bluetooth: HCI UART protocol Intel registered
[    8.323711] Bluetooth: HCI UART protocol BCM registered
[    8.323711] Bluetooth: HCI UART protocol QCA registered
[    8.323711] Bluetooth: HCI UART protocol AG6XX registered
[    8.439889] Bluetooth: hci0: Bootloader revision 0.0 build 26 week 38 2015
[    8.441167] Bluetooth: hci0: Device revision is 16
[    8.441168] Bluetooth: hci0: Secure boot is enabled
[    8.441168] Bluetooth: hci0: OTP lock is enabled
[    8.441169] Bluetooth: hci0: API lock is enabled
[    8.441169] Bluetooth: hci0: Debug lock is disabled
[    8.441170] Bluetooth: hci0: Minimum firmware build 1 week 10 2014
[    8.441475] bluetooth hci0: Direct firmware load for intel/ibt-12-16.sfi failed with error -2
[    8.441476] Bluetooth: hci0: Failed to load Intel firmware file (-2)
[    8.628714] Bluetooth: hci0: Bootloader revision 0.0 build 26 week 38 2015
[    8.631223] Bluetooth: hci0: Device revision is 16
[    8.631224] Bluetooth: hci0: Secure boot is enabled
[    8.631225] Bluetooth: hci0: OTP lock is enabled
[    8.631225] Bluetooth: hci0: API lock is enabled
[    8.631225] Bluetooth: hci0: Debug lock is disabled
[    8.631226] Bluetooth: hci0: Minimum firmware build 1 week 10 2014
[    8.631234] bluetooth hci0: Direct firmware load for intel/ibt-12-16.sfi failed with error -2
[    8.631235] Bluetooth: hci0: Failed to load Intel firmware file (-2)
[    8.794982] Bluetooth: BNEP (Ethernet Emulation) ver 1.3
[    8.794983] Bluetooth: BNEP filters: protocol multicast
[    8.794986] Bluetooth: BNEP socket layer initialized

$ lsusb
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 0c45:670c Microdia 
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 8087:0a2b Intel Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 413c:301d Dell Computer Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of `dmesg | grep -i blue`  and `lsusb` terminal commands.

Comment: I have added output of required commands. I verified that intel/ibt-12-16.sfi file does not exists on my firmware folder, but I have only ibt-11-5.sfi and ibt-11-16.sfi... I suppose I have to get it somewhere?

Comment: See the answer. The device is fully supported from 16.10, but it is fixable for 16.04.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to install firmware for this adapter. It is not in the `linux-firmware` package for 16.04. You can install firmware from 16.10 this way:

```
wget http://mirrors.kernel.org/ubuntu/pool/main/l/linux-firmware/linux-firmware_1.161.1_all.deb
sudo dpkg -i linux-firmware_1.161.1_all.deb
```