# Bluetooth: where to get intel/ibt-12-16.sfi firmware for Ubuntu 14.04? (Thinkpad X1 Yoga Gen2)

Tags: 14.04, bluetooth

The symptom (bluetooth switch can only be set to off), and the error message I got is almost the same as in this [question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/881239/bluetooth-not-working-on-xps-13-9360-running-16-04-1) but I am running 14.04, 64 bit. Is it possible that I get this firmware for 14.04? Thanks!

```
$ lspci -nn
00:00.0 Host bridge [0600]: Intel Corporation Device [8086:5904] (rev 02)
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller [0300]: Intel Corporation Device [8086:5916] (rev 02)
00:08.0 System peripheral [0880]: Intel Corporation Sky Lake Gaussian Mixture Model [8086:1911]
00:13.0 Non-VGA unclassified device [0000]: Intel Corporation Device [8086:9d35] (rev 21)
00:14.0 USB controller [0c03]: Intel Corporation Device [8086:9d2f] (rev 21)
00:14.2 Signal processing controller [1180]: Intel Corporation Device [8086:9d31] (rev 21)
00:16.0 Communication controller [0780]: Intel Corporation Device [8086:9d3a] (rev 21)
00:1c.0 PCI bridge [0604]: Intel Corporation Device [8086:9d10] (rev f1)
00:1c.2 PCI bridge [0604]: Intel Corporation Device [8086:9d12] (rev f1)
00:1c.4 PCI bridge [0604]: Intel Corporation Device [8086:9d14] (rev f1)
00:1d.0 PCI bridge [0604]: Intel Corporation Device [8086:9d18] (rev f1)
00:1f.0 ISA bridge [0601]: Intel Corporation Device [8086:9d4e] (rev 21)
00:1f.2 Memory controller [0580]: Intel Corporation Device [8086:9d21] (rev 21)
00:1f.3 Audio device [0403]: Intel Corporation Device [8086:9d71] (rev 21)
00:1f.4 SMBus [0c05]: Intel Corporation Device [8086:9d23] (rev 21)
00:1f.6 Ethernet controller [0200]: Intel Corporation Device [8086:15d7] (rev 21)
02:00.0 Unassigned class [ff00]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. Device [10ec:525a] (rev 01)
04:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Intel Corporation Device [8086:24fd] (rev 88)
05:00.0 Non-Volatile memory controller [0108]: Samsung Electronics Co Ltd Device [144d:a804]

$ rfkill list all
0: tpacpi_bluetooth_sw: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
1: hci0: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
2: acer-wireless: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
3: phy0: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no

$ uname -r
4.4.0-128-generic

$ dmesg | grep -i blue
[    3.722986] thinkpad_acpi: rfkill switch tpacpi_bluetooth_sw: radio is unblocked
[    3.730841] Bluetooth: Core ver 2.21
[    3.730864] Bluetooth: HCI device and connection manager initialized
[    3.730867] Bluetooth: HCI socket layer initialized
[    3.730870] Bluetooth: L2CAP socket layer initialized
[    3.730874] Bluetooth: SCO socket layer initialized
[    3.741702] Bluetooth: BNEP (Ethernet Emulation) ver 1.3
[    3.741704] Bluetooth: BNEP filters: protocol multicast
[    3.741708] Bluetooth: BNEP socket layer initialized
[    3.750410] Bluetooth: RFCOMM TTY layer initialized
[    3.750416] Bluetooth: RFCOMM socket layer initialized
[    3.750424] Bluetooth: RFCOMM ver 1.11
[    3.754942] Bluetooth: hci0: Bootloader revision 0.0 build 26 week 38 2015
[    3.755942] Bluetooth: hci0: Device revision is 16
[    3.755944] Bluetooth: hci0: Secure boot is enabled
[    3.755945] Bluetooth: hci0: OTP lock is enabled
[    3.755946] Bluetooth: hci0: API lock is enabled
[    3.755947] Bluetooth: hci0: Debug lock is disabled
[    3.755949] Bluetooth: hci0: Minimum firmware build 1 week 10 2014
[    3.756673] bluetooth hci0: Direct firmware load for intel/ibt-12-16.sfi failed with error -2
[    3.756675] Bluetooth: hci0: Failed to load Intel firmware file (-2)
```

EDIT: As suggested in the answer, I tried

```
cd /lib/firmware/intel
sudo wget https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/firmware/linux-firmware.git/plain/intel/ibt-12-16.sfi
```

and reboot. The bluetooth now shows up but it still cannot detect my headset. Here is what I get:

```
$ dmesg | grep -i blue
[    4.124090] Bluetooth: Core ver 2.21
[    4.124144] Bluetooth: HCI device and connection manager initialized
[    4.124148] Bluetooth: HCI socket layer initialized
[    4.124151] Bluetooth: L2CAP socket layer initialized
[    4.124156] Bluetooth: SCO socket layer initialized
[    4.172259] Bluetooth: hci0: Bootloader revision 0.0 build 26 week 38 2015
[    4.173265] Bluetooth: hci0: Device revision is 16
[    4.173267] Bluetooth: hci0: Secure boot is enabled
[    4.173268] Bluetooth: hci0: OTP lock is enabled
[    4.173269] Bluetooth: hci0: API lock is enabled
[    4.173270] Bluetooth: hci0: Debug lock is disabled
[    4.173272] Bluetooth: hci0: Minimum firmware build 1 week 10 2014
[    4.174894] Bluetooth: hci0: Found device firmware: intel/ibt-12-16.sfi
[    4.191942] thinkpad_acpi: rfkill switch tpacpi_bluetooth_sw: radio is unblocked
[    4.222505] Bluetooth: BNEP (Ethernet Emulation) ver 1.3
[    4.222507] Bluetooth: BNEP filters: protocol multicast
[    4.222510] Bluetooth: BNEP socket layer initialized
[    4.231315] Bluetooth: RFCOMM TTY layer initialized
[    4.231324] Bluetooth: RFCOMM socket layer initialized
[    4.231328] Bluetooth: RFCOMM ver 1.11
[    5.614323] Bluetooth: hci0: Waiting for firmware download to complete
[    5.614325] Bluetooth: hci0: Firmware loaded in 1409448 usecs
[    5.614391] Bluetooth: hci0: Waiting for device to boot
[    5.631368] Bluetooth: hci0: Device booted in 16627 usecs
[    5.631382] Bluetooth: hci0: Failed to load Intel DDC file intel/ibt-12-16.ddc (-2)
```

How should I proceed?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could try

```
cd /lib/firmware/intel
sudo wget https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/firmware/linux-firmware.git/plain/intel/ibt-12-16.sfi
```

Then reboot

The upstream Intel bluetooth firmware can be found at https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/firmware/linux-firmware.git/tree/intel

EDIT

```
cd /lib/firmware/intel
sudo wget https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/firmware/linux-firmware.git/plain/intel/ibt-12-16.ddc
```

Reboot

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. This does something, but still not quite there. I've updated my question with the new results.

Comment: It works! It connects with my phone now, although not my 2 headphones. I am going to assume that is due to some other issues.

Answer (score 0):

If your wireless card is too new to be supported out-of-the-box, you may have to extract the correct `.ucode` firmware file from the archives linked from

https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/support/articles/000005511/network-and-i-o/wireless.html

to `/lib/firmware` and reboot. The "missing sfi" error message will disappear and Bluetooth will start working.

You could check `dmesg | grep iwlwifi` for additional debugging.